# how to run resque startup script from bash with full path

Tags: linux, bash, resque

I am trying to run the following command:

```
/A/B/C/D/E/RAILS_ENV=staging rake deploy:resque
```

And the get the following error

```
-bash: /A/B/C/D/E/RAILS_ENV=staging: No such file or directory
```

But when i run the command directly from the folder it works nicely.
I don't quite understand how it is supposed to work

Thanks.

Comment: What is `/A/B/C/D/E/` supposed to be there? A path to `rake`? A path to a `resque` binary?

Comment: path to rails application

Comment: And how does that get used by `rake` or `resque`? Is that supposed to be the value of `RAILS_ENV`? Is that supposed to be an argument to `resque`? An argument to `rake`? How are you supposed to supply that path to the rails application to `rake`/`resque`? (Or is that the question here?)

Comment: I am not sure myself to tell you the truth, It is more of a bash question. what is working from the directory itself should work with a full path as well.... what is the difference?

Comment: You aren't giving a full path to a binary there. You are putting a full path on an environment variable which then makes it a path to a binary which fails (since `/A/B/C/D/E/RAILS_ENV=staging` isn't a binary on your system). Did you mean `RAILS_ENV=staging /A/B/C/D/E/rake deploy:resque`? To give an absolute path to `rake`? (I doubt it but maybe.)

Comment: ok, i'll look into it more closely you gave me some direction... thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /A/B/C/D/E && RAILS_ENV=staging; rake deploy:resque
```